# Submit input doesn't triggers anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, input

I have some rails app but my `submit` button doesn't triggers anything. (Ia m using twitter bootstrap). Here's the `tag`

```
<input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Sign up" name="commit">
```

When I click on it, nothing happens. Perhaps there is some "prevent default" method in `bootstrap` but how can I debug this ?

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="panel-body" data-validate="true" id="new_user" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="TOWfy1DjcfzzIoCe/BYdEfsKf5gyW902uiyAZxq2GVw="></div>
           <div class="block">
               <label class="control-label" for="user_user_name">User name</label>
               <input class="form-control" id="user_user_name" name="user[user_name]" placeholder="username" type="text" data-validate="true">
           </div>

</a>           <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Sign up" name="commit">
           <div class="line line-dashed"></div>
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-facebook btn-circle btn-sm"><i class="icon-facebook"></i>Sign up with Facebook</a>
             </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-twitter btn-circle btn-sm" href="/users/auth/twitter">
            <i class="icon-twitter"></i>Sign up with Twitter
</a>        </div>

           </div>
           <div class="line line-dashed"></div>
</form>
```

My rails code (the above code was essentially the product of what follows, I have deleted unneccessary `inputs`) :

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :validate => true, :html => {:class => "panel-body"}, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
           <%= devise_error_messages! %>
           <div class="block">
               <%= f.label :user_name, :class=>"control-label"%>
               <%= f.text_field :user_name, :autofocus => true, :placeholder=>"username", :class=>"form-control" %>
           </div>
           <div class="block">
             <%= f.label :email, :class=>"control-label"%>
             <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :placeholder=>"email", :class=>"form-control" %>
           </div>
           <div class="block">
             <%= f.label :password, :class=>"control-label"%>
             <%= f.password_field :password, :autofocus => true, :placeholder=>"password", :id=>"inputPassword", :class=>"form-control" %>
           </div>
           <div class="block">
             <%= f.label :password_confirmation, :class=>"control-label"%>
             <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :autofocus => true, :placeholder=>"confirm password", :id=>"inputPassword", :class=>"form-control" %>
           </div>
           <div class="checkbox">
             <label>
               <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service, {}, true, false %> Agree the <%= link_to "terms and policy" %>
             </label>
           </div>
           <%= link_to dees_path, :class=>"pull-right m-t-mini" do%>
             Forgot password? <%= content_tag(:small, "", :class => "") %>
           <% end %>
           <%= f.submit "Sign up", class:"btn btn-info" %>
           <div class="line line-dashed"></div>
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-facebook btn-circle btn-sm"><i class="icon-facebook"></i>Sign up with Facebook</a>
             </div>
             <%= render "devise/shared/connect_social_links" %>
           </div>
           <div class="line line-dashed"></div>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: Sadly, I'm not expert enough in Rails to extrapolate your entire code based on one input button. Please provide us with a little more context.

Comment: Have you included form tag in your page

Comment: do you have a form surrounding it ?

Comment: sure I have a form surrounding it !

Comment: but do you see where we're coming from? we can't see your code other than what you have provided. that input alone should do nothing, as you are describing.

Comment: What is the form action?

Comment: Indentation is all over the place, but i don't see anything that would prevent it from submitting. bootstrap doesn't stop my forms from submitting.

Comment: Well, [your form works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/eNrGg/), although that stray `</a>` tag is mysterious. What does your Rails code look like?

Comment: @Blazemonger I use client side validation gem. Perhaps it has to deal with that

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors? Open the browser dev console and check.

Comment: @CoolTapes none, nothing shows up when validating

Comment: @Blazemonger I tried to put this code `$('.btn-info').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/users',beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
        type: 'post',
        
    });
});` but the rails request to the database seems to be `SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1`, but no insert. How can it be ?

Comment: Maybe `:validate => true` prevents the form from submitting and (for some reason) doesn't show error messages.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to make sure your application is actually receiving the "submit" call. If it's not, then it's a problem with your HTML form, it if is, then it's a problem with the way you've used Rails to define the form

Here's what I would do:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on('submit', '.panel-body', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('submit');
});
```

This allows you to see if the submit function is actually firing. After that, you'll be able to gauge whether it's the form's data itself which is causing the issue.

As I see you're using Devise, you may have not defined the `form_for` variables correctly. IF you try the recommendation I have posted, and then reply in the comments on how it performs, I'll be in a much stronger position to help you